# "get out and about" meaning

Tags: idiom-meaning

I have encountered the term "get out and about", in one of Oxford's books. It seems to be quite a problem to conclude what exactly it means. I have not found this phrase neither in my national translator, nor on the internet (cambridge, oxford, idoceonline websites etc.)
There is an explanation in my Oxford textbook:

> "go to places where you can meet people"

Example:

> There is an old lady who does not get out and about much.

But does this phrase (for example) include even meeting other people and get to know them? Or is it only about going to a place where we expect some other people?

Answer (score 1):

[Out and About] refers to physically experiencing something beyond one's ordinary environment, to enjoy for the pleasure of it or learn what can only be learned beyond one's ordinary environment.  The 'out' refers to [out of one's ordinary environment] and the 'about' refers to more than one other place or an extended period of time.  Out and About would not include running to the grocery store alone, or running to the end of the driveway alone; it requires multiple places or an extended period of time/experiences.

As for requiring 'people,' no it does not require that.  It's focus is more on what happens within a person when they do it, not who or what they will affect when they do.  People can enjoy or learn from many things, including other people, but they can enjoy and learn from 'getting out and about' with noone around too.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, I can put the meaning into this short explanation: "go out for (pleasant) experiences".
It it roughly correct?

Comment: you can 'go out' for many reasons...the phrase does not imply intention, except to not remain in (inside or in one's ordinary or current environment).  As for 'experiences,' while it is true people 'go out for' them, sometimes they just what to get away from where they currently are, so when you add that word, you are clarifying intention...to get experiences, in lieu of just 'out.'  Finally, 'go out' mentions no particular place or destination, more of a 'free' act as opposed to specific purpose/destination.

Answer (score 0):

The expression, to my knowledge, does not connote or contain the expectation of "meeting other people and get(ting) to know them?". It was/is used to indicate that someone transitions from a perhaps sheltered, indoor environment - to an outdoor social environment - and not just to stand on a busy street corner - but to go to an event or destination where others would gather. There could be a secondary implication that perhaps this "someone" might meet whomever - for an extra (even temporary) spice in their life. However, in its simplest use, it is meant to indicate activity in direct contrast to "staying at home".  Best,   JFC